# Mysqli select query based on two different fields

Tags: php, mysql

Here is My Table Structure
**Table : sales**

```
invoice_no  prd_code    quantity    unit_price  discount    tax total_tax   date    delet
   135          1          1            120         0        5      0     1/8/2016      1
   135          1          1            120         0        5      0     1/8/2016      0
   135          2          3            30          0        0      0     1/8/2016      0
   135          3          1            165         0        5      0     1/8/2016      0
   136          2          4            30          3        5      0     1/16/2016     0
   136          1          2            120         0        0      5     1/16/2016     0
   136          1          2            120         0        0      5     1/16/2016     1
   136          1          2            120         0        0      5     1/16/2016     1
   137          1          2            120         0        0      0     1/15/2016     0
   137          1          2            120         0        0      0     1/15/2016     0
   138          2          12           30          0        0      6     1/16/2016     0
   138          3          10           165         0        0      6     1/16/2016     0
```

Here is my Html Code

```
<input type = "date" id = "fmdte" name = "fmdte" class = "form-control" />
<input type = "date" id = "todate" name = "todate" class = "form-control" />
<input type = "text" id = "tax" name = "tax" class = "form-control" />
<input type = "submit" id = "ser" name = "ser" value = "Search" />
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['ser']))
{
   $fmdt = $_POST['fmdte'];
   $todt = $_POST['todate'];
   $tax_ser = $_POST['tax'];
   $purqry = $db->execute("select * from sales where date BETWEEN '$fmdt' and '$todt' and (tax='$tax_ser' OR total_tax='$tax_ser') and delet='0'"); //,order_no
}
```

In this table there is two fields one is **tax** and other one is **total_tax** the tax field is used to store item wise tax and the total_tax is used to store total tax in an invoice.
Initially default value of two fields are Zero if a value store in tax field (!=0) total_tax value store as Zero, if a value store in total_tax field (!=0) tax field value store as Zero some time no values stored in **tax and total_tax** fields  so its default value is Zero.
 I want to Search **Zero Tax** items combine tax and total_tax fields
How to search tax=0 and total_tax=0 **(avoid tax>0 and total_tax>0)**

Comment: But there is no `returnd` field in the table schema then why you are adding this in query?

Comment: Share the table fields data types too;

Comment: quantity : Double,    unit_price : Double,  discount : Double,    tax : Double, total_tax : Double, Date : Date

Comment: Check the data form you are getting from from and exists in your db;

Comment: i search Tax and total_tax as Zero it returns all data in my db between two dates, but i search tax =5 it returns correct answer. Zero is problem

Answer (score 0):

let try it

```
    if (isset($_POST['ser']))
    {
         $fmdt = $_POST['fmdte'];
         $todt = $_POST['todate'];
         $tax_ser = $_POST['tax'];

         //use concat when passing variable value
         $purqry = $db->execute("select * from sales ".
         "where (date BETWEEN '". $fmdt ."' and '". $todt ."') ".
         "and (tax= ". $tax_ser ." OR total_tax= ". $tax_ser .") and delet='0' "); //,order_no
    }
```

Comment: try sql in phymyadmin first, then applicate that query in php code

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution..

```
if (isset($_POST['ser'])) {
    $fmdt = $_POST['fmdte'];
    $todt = $_POST['todate'];
    $tax_ser = $_POST['tax'];
    if ($tax_ser == '0') {
        $purqry = $db->execute("select * from sales where date BETWEEN '$fmdt' and '$todt' and (tax='$tax_ser' and total_tax='$tax_ser') and delet='0'");
    }
    else {
        $purqry = $db->execute("select * from sales where date BETWEEN '$fmdt' and '$todt' and (tax='$tax_ser' OR total_tax='$tax_ser') and delet='0'");
    }
}
```